# usage golang atomic LoadInt32/StoreInt32 (64)

Tags: go, atomic

Can anybody show the example where usage of such atomic operations needed. I don't understand a differenece between

```
import "sync/atomic"

...
var sharedA int64
var sharedB *int64
...
// concurent code
tmpVarA := sharedA
tmpVarB := *sharedB
// and
tmpVarA := atomic.LoadInt64(&sharedA)
tmpVarB := atomic.LoadInt64(sharedB)
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use anything from sync/atomic. Never ever. But you asked: sync/atomic allows to read e.g. int64 in a race-free manner. If you mix reading and writing without synchronization through channels or stuff from package sync) your code is racy which means it has undefined behaviour.  Now sometimes it is easier to force a "non-racy" read of an int64 with atomic.LoadInt64 than explicit synchronisation. But as said: Never do this.

Answer (score 8):

It's not documented in the package at all, but normally atomic loads and stores of normal values are there not for atomicity because the CPU operations are already atomic, but for ordering. The language specification or CPU instruction documentation gives you certain guarantees about in which order one CPU stores will be seen by another CPU if you use the atomic operations. Most modern CPUs have no such guarantees if you don't use the proper (expensive) instructions for it.

So in your example (I assume, since the package isn't documented), if the shared variables have been written by a goroutine first to `sharedA`, then `sharedB`, when reading then without atomic operations you might see the changed value of `sharedB` and still the old value of `sharedA`. It's different on different CPU families if the stores or loads need to perform extra magic to get the ordering right, so usually languages make you use atomic functions for both stores and loads and then the compiler/library knows what your actual CPU needs.

Of course, the package doesn't document any of this, so in practice there is no difference because we don't know what the package actually guarantees. So for all practical purposes it's useless.

Comment: but why we need load operation?  `AddInt32`  is enough, isn't it?

Comment: I could imagine that on a 32 bit machine a 64 bit load/write is not atomic. You don't want to read the unmodified lower 32 bits and the modified upper 32 bits.

Comment: Are you sure "normal load and stores" of int64 are atomic on all supported platforms? Even on the 32-bit platforms? Also: The memory model does not mention that the operations in syn/atomic establish a HB relation.

Comment: the interesting thing that go race detector finds and informes this case as racecondition

`gorotine1:...Shared2 = 12345;..gorotine2.. readshared:= Shared2`

but if you wrap them with sync.Lock - it thinks that now everething is ok.

Comment: @JiangYD On some architectures (and I'm pretty sure modern x86 is one of them) synchronization is best done before loads and not after stores.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov because sync.Lock has built-in ordering guarantees, which as I see now aren't documented either. But if we assume that it behaves like "everyone else", any writes done before a Unlock in one goroutine will be visible to other goroutines after their call to Lock. Unfortunately the memory model of Go isn't very well documented, so I can only make reasonable assumptions from how the CPUs and other languages behave.

Comment: @Art the synchronisation and HB guarantees of package sync are documented in the Go Memory Model, see e.g. https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_8 .