# sync/atomic StoreInt32 strange behavior

Tags: go, atomic

This code is simplified and describes my problem. It seems that `atomic.StoreInt32` not work but I'm not sure why.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type slave struct {
    failed int32
}
func NewSlave() slave {
    return slave{0}
}
func (worker slave) Fail() {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&worker.failed, 1) // Here's the problem.
}
func (worker slave) IsFailed() bool {
    failed := atomic.LoadInt32(&worker.failed) == 1
    return failed
}
func (worker slave) FailureReset() {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&worker.failed, 0)
}

func main() {
    s := NewSlave()
    fmt.Println(s.IsFailed())
    s.Fail()
    fmt.Println(s.IsFailed())
    s.FailureReset()
    fmt.Println(s.IsFailed())
}
```

->output:

```
false 0
false 0
false 0
```

->tested on:

```
recolic@RECOLICPC ~/tmp> go version
go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64
recolic@RECOLICPC ~/tmp> uname -a
Linux RECOLICPC 4.13.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 8 11:54:06 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've read: [usage golang atomic LoadInt32/StoreInt32 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542609/usage-golang-atomic-loadint32-storeint32-64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your methods take a pointer receiver. As written, the functions are operating on a copy of your worker, so the worker used to invoke the method is not changed. Define the methods like this:

```
func (worker *slave) Fail() {
    // ...
}
```